# Simple queueing system for parallel processes

Tags: software-recommendation, 22.04, batch

I want to setup a queueing system for my workstation, which has 32 processors.
In principle, I would not connect it with any other workstation.

I mean to use a system which is simple to configure and use.
I do not care if it does not have a terrific versatility, suitable for HPC on large clusters, etc.

I read the HTCondor might be one such application.
Is there any packaged version for Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Alternatively, is there any other reasonable package for this?

I found one other question about this, but it is very old.

Comment: fyi. this tutorial seems promising!: https://wasteofserver.com/htcondor-install-and-configure-as-non-root

Answer (score 0):

** THIS IS A LENGTHY COMMENT, NOT A SOLUTION **

I am in the same boat, familiar with htcondor because of work, and wanted to install this in my own pcs.

I believe the current "popular" job queueing systems for HPC Centers are HTCondor, Slurm and [perhaps also Torque/Moab](https://info.nrao.edu/computing/guide/cluster-processing/appendix/translating-between-torque-htcondor-and-slurm).

As of 2022-Dec, per HTCondor's [documentation](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/v10_0/getting-htcondor/index.html), htcondor is not yet providing a release for Ubuntu 22.04 ([supported ubuntu versions are be found here](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/repo/ubuntu/current/dists))

That said, per this [documentation](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/v10_0/getting-htcondor/install-linux-as-user.html#download), they do provide other builds in a [seperate location](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/tarball/current/10.3.0/daily), and for v10.3.0, there is a tar file for Ubuntu22: "
[condor-10.3.0-x86_64_Ubuntu22-stripped.tar.gz](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/tarball/current/10.3.0/daily/condor-10.3.0-x86_64_Ubuntu22-stripped.tar.gz)".
I tried to follow the [old](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/tutorials/cw2006-milan/install_condor.html) installation steps, but am not able to get services to start after running `condor_master`.  I am now trying the installation steps provided in the below link: https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/v8_8/admin-manual/installation-startup-shutdown-reconfiguration.html#unix-installation-from-a-tarball

--

Will update this post if I ever get htcondor to install to ubuntu 22.04...

--

edit: caved in and just added 20.04 vms via promox.